GoCardless Error 403 Forbidden during User Creation (works in sandbox but fails in live environment)
I'm using the GoCardless API to create customers and mandates, and the code works perfectly fine in the sandbox environment. However, when I switch to the live environment, I receive a 403 Forbidden error during customer creation.
def create_gocardless_customer(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    try:
        print("Inizio processo di associazione/creazione cliente GoCardless")  # Debug

        # Verifica dei campi obbligatori
        if not self.surname:
            raise UserError("Il campo 'Cognome' è obbligatorio.")
        if not self.pec and not self.email:
            raise UserError("Il campo 'Email' è obbligatorio.")
        if (not self.pec and ("@" not in self.email or "." not in self.email)) or (
                self.pec and ("@" not in self.pec or "." not in self.pec)):
            raise UserError("L'indirizzo email fornito non è valido.")
        if not self.iban:
            raise UserError("Il campo 'IBAN' è obbligatorio.")

        print("Campi obbligatori verificati")  # Debug

        # Creazione del client GoCardless
        client = gocardless_pro.Client(
            access_token=token,
            environment='live'
        )
        print("Client GoCardless creato con successo")  # Debug

        # Ricerca del cliente tramite email
        customer = None
        customers_list = client.customers.list()
        print("Lista clienti recuperata:", customers_list.records)  # Stampa la lista dei clienti
        for existing_customer in customers_list.records:
            if existing_customer.email == (self.pec if self.pec else self.email):
                customer = existing_customer
                print(f"Cliente esistente trovato con ID: {customer.id}")  # Debug
                self.id_gocardless = customer.id
                break

        # Creazione del cliente se non esiste
        if not customer:
            customer_data = {
                "given_name": self.name,
                "family_name": self.surname,
                "email": self.pec if self.pec else self.email,
                "address_line1": " ",
                "city": " ",
                "postal_code": " ",
                "country_code": "IT"
            }
            print(f"Creazione nuovo cliente con i seguenti dati: {customer_data}")  # Debug
            customer = client.customers.create(params=customer_data)
            self.id_gocardless = customer.id
            self.env.cr.commit()

        # Verifica se esiste già un account bancario con lo stesso IBAN (utilizzando 'account_number_ending')
        existing_bank_accounts = client.customer_bank_accounts.list(params={"customer": customer.id})
        print("Lista account bancari per il cliente:",
              existing_bank_accounts.records)  # Debug lista account bancari

        for account in existing_bank_accounts.records:
            print(f"Account number ending: {account.attributes['account_number_ending']}")  # Debug

        matching_account = next(
            (account for account in existing_bank_accounts.records if
             account.attributes['account_number_ending'] == self.iban[-2:]),
            None
        )

        if matching_account:
            print(f"Account bancario esistente trovato con ID: {matching_account.attributes['id']}")  # Debug
            self.bank_account_id = matching_account.attributes['id']
            # Verifica se esiste un mandato attivo
            existing_mandates = client.mandates.list(
                params={"customer_bank_account": matching_account.attributes['id']})
            print("Lista mandati per account bancario:", existing_mandates.records)  # Debug lista mandati
            active_mandate = next(
                (mandate for mandate in existing_mandates.records if mandate.status == 'active'),
                None
            )
            if active_mandate:
                print(f"Mandato attivo esistente trovato con ID: {active_mandate.id}")  # Debug
                self.mandato_id = active_mandate.id
            else:
                # Crea un nuovo mandato se non esiste un mandato attivo
                mandate_data = {
                    "scheme": "sepa_core",
                    "links": {
                        "customer_bank_account": matching_account.attributes['id']
                    }
                }
                mandate = client.mandates.create(params=mandate_data)
                print(f"Nuovo mandato creato con ID: {mandate.id}")  # Debug
                self.mandato_id = mandate.id
        else:
            try:
                # Solo se non esiste un account bancario con lo stesso IBAN, creazione nuovo account bancario e mandato
                bank_account_data = {
                    "iban": self.iban,
                    "account_holder_name": f"{self.name} {self.surname}",
                    "country_code": "IT",
                    "links": {
                        "customer": customer.id
                    }
                }
                print(f"Creazione nuovo account bancario con i seguenti dati: {bank_account_data}")  # Debug
                new_bank_account = client.customer_bank_accounts.create(params=bank_account_data)
                print(f"Nuovo account bancario creato con ID: {new_bank_account.id}")  # Debug
                self.bank_account_id = new_bank_account.id
                mandate_data = {
                    "scheme": "sepa_core",
                    "links": {
                        "customer_bank_account": new_bank_account.id
                    }
                }
                mandate = client.mandates.create(params=mandate_data)
                print(f"Nuovo mandato creato con ID: {mandate.id}")  # Debug
                self.mandato_id = mandate.id
            except Exception as e:
                if "Bank account already exists" in str(e):
                    # Se l'account esiste già, recuperalo
                    existing_bank_accounts = client.customer_bank_accounts.list(params={"customer": customer.id})
                    matching_account = next(
                        (account for account in existing_bank_accounts.records if
                         account.attributes['account_number_ending'] == self.iban[-2:] and
                         account.attributes['account_holder_name'] == f"{self.name} {self.surname}"),
                        None
                    )
                    if matching_account:
                        print(
                            f"Account bancario esistente trovato con ID: {matching_account.attributes['id']} dopo errore di creazione")  # Debug
                        self.bank_account_id = matching_account.attributes['id']
                        existing_mandates = client.mandates.list(
                            params={"customer_bank_account": matching_account.attributes['id']})
                        active_mandate = next(
                            (mandate for mandate in existing_mandates.records if mandate.status == 'active'),
                            None
                        )
                        if active_mandate:
                            print(f"Mandato attivo esistente trovato con ID: {active_mandate.id}")  # Debug
                            self.mandato_id = active_mandate.id
                        else:
                            # Crea un nuovo mandato se non esiste un mandato attivo
                            mandate_data = {
                                "scheme": "sepa_core",
                                "links": {
                                    "customer_bank_account": matching_account.attributes['id']
                                }
                            }
                            mandate = client.mandates.create(params=mandate_data)
                            print(f"Nuovo mandato creato con ID: {mandate.id}")  # Debug
                            self.mandato_id = mandate.id
                else:
                    raise

        self.env.cr.commit()
        print("Operazione completata con successo")  # Debug

    except PermissionsError as e:
        print(f"Errore di permessi GoCardless: {e}")  # Debug
        raise UserError(f"Errore di permessi GoCardless: {e}")
    except InvalidApiUsageError as e:
        print(f"Errore di utilizzo API GoCardless: {e}")  # Debug
        raise UserError(f"Errore di utilizzo API GoCardless: {e}")
    except InvalidStateError as e:
        print(f"Errore di stato GoCardless: {e}")  # Debug
        raise UserError(f"Errore di stato GoCardless: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Errore GoCardless generico: {e}")  # Debug
        raise UserError(f"Errore GoCardless: {e}")

Sandbox environment: The customer creation process works perfectly, and I can create customers and mandates without any issues.
Live environment: I receive a 403 Forbidden error when trying to create a customer.
